# ReadLine issues

Tags: c#, string, console, int, readline

I need to make a Console Application in C# that will take in numbers and lines

x for any number

xxxx-xx-xxxxxx

or 4 numbers, line, 2 numbers, line, 6 numbers.

The suggested method is to ask for user input and confirm if the user didn't write integers and place lines in the right places.

I'd like to place it in a format so the user wont have to write the lines himself.

I'd like the lines to be automatically inserted so the user wont have to place them, the length of the string is also always the same. (0-13 or 14 chars)

Can this be done in any fairly simple way?

**Edit**:
I wrote and added the code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cAt53NTV) (since its rather long to put it all into here)

This code takes the string input and makes sure no invalid characters were entered, in other words it works but i want the program to place '-' where they should be automatically in any way. and it would also be nice to be able to limit the amount of characters you can enter (to 14, including lines.)

My primary issue is to be able to place the '-' automatically while still being able to use backspace.

Sorry if the code is primitive, its a school project and i'm still learning. this is the method they "want me" to use.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code? Stack Overflow does not write your code for you.

Comment: by `line` I assume you mean `dash character`.  Please be precise in your question.

Comment: Yep, add a 100~ + pt bounty and watch the magic unfold.

Comment: I haven't written anything yet, at first i wanted just to know if it was possible. but i'll wrote some code and check back after i've done it, if no reply will be here then i will add it to the main post

Comment: Can you guarantee that the input will include only integers and dashes? Do you have to use readline? And of course it is possible, either way.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Please write your code and make the question answerable as result.

Comment: Code has been written.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (hardcoded for a string of length 14 with dashes at position 4 and 7). It will intercept all input from the user and check if it is a digit. If it is a digit, it prints it out and adds it to the input. Additionally, it will print out a dash when the input length has reached some point.

```
     String input = "";
     while (input.Length < 14)
     {
        char c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
        if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) // ASCII code for a digit (between 0 and 9)
        {
           input += c; // add digit to input
           Console.Write(c); // output it to the console
        }
        if (input.Length == 4 || input.Length == 7)
        {
           input += "-";
           Console.Write("-"); // add dash to the input and write it to console
        }
     }
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but doesn't allow me to use backspace. and also doesn't allow me to write all i want within 14 chars and then press enter (i can only press numbers between 0 and 9) i figured out ascii code for backspace is "9" but that didn't help much. adding an or for that it still is going to count as an extra character, nice attempt tho! thanks :) i learned a few things.

It would be enough for me to be able to just add the "-" where they belong allowing the user to input wrong characters though, them i have to verify with an if anyways.

Comment: Why would you want to allow the user to input invalid characters?

Comment: It is unimportant, the whole purpose of the program is to make sure that no invalid characters were entered anywhere. theres nothing to test if the option for making invalid characters isn't there.

I just most importantly need to be able to use backspace to erase what's been written, and enter to confirm the string after i write it (i don't want to automatically hop into the code after i write the set amount of chars)